# Google Drive API -- Root ID

Tags: google-drive-api

Does a Root ID in google drive always start with "0A" and end with "Uk9PVA"? Is it always 19 characters? Are any other objects other than Drive Root IDs in that format? I haven't found any exception to rule but I wonder if it is something that is documented that I can rely upon (ie, with a regex).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use ``root`` as the ID for retrieving root folder. ``You can use the alias root to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided`` The document is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder).

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, but I'm aware of that. Spefically, in the "parents" field, a list of IDs are given. I want to be able to distinguish between root parents and non-root parents reliably without making a separate API call.

Comment: I'm really sorry I misunderstood about your situation. In my experience, when the ID is retrieved by ``root``, I confirmed that ``0A###########Uk9PVA`` is returned and this value is returned at several accounts. I think that it can say that the ID trends to the value like ``0A###########Uk9PVA``. But at least, I think that it can say that the length of ID of ``root`` is surely the shortest of all folder IDs.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, that was my experience too, but still anecdotal. I think I could work off that assumption and then throw an exception if I encounter any issue. Hopefully someone from the Google team sees this!

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.